# jquery clone only element's content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in jQuery to clone an element's content? Not the entire element, only the content(children).

Something similar to what `.html()` is doing, but I'm also interested in cloning the events attached to the content.

I was looking at `.clone`, but it seems that is cloning the entire element.

Thanks.

Comment: Loop throught all children and copy them?

Comment: the events attached to the elements are not cloned

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Doua Beri, with reference to [the jQuery API documentation for `.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) you will find that what you want is `.clone(true,true)`. This will make a deep copy of an element (or a collection of elements), including all data and event bindings.

You then have a choice of two options as to how you use `.clone(true,true)`.

1. Clone the children individually to give a jQuery collection comprising clones of the children.

   `var $childClones = $("#myElement").children().clone(true,true);`
2. Clone the outer element to give a jQuery collection comprising a clone of the outer element, itself containing clones of the children.

   `var $clone = $("#myElement").clone(true,true);`

It is somewhat academic which approach you adopt. In both cases the descendant elements are available collectively or individually to be manipulated and/or inserted into the DOM, though the code to do so would differ slightly.

Answer (score 6):

If you like a deep-copy just clone the children:

`$('#footer-flair').children().clone()`

And instead of attaching events to particular elements attach an event to a container element that is listening to child elements, that way your events will fire as long as the container element stays even if you add/remove a thousand elements inside the container. You could do this on the body tag if you never want your events to go away.

Use the 'on' method to bind events like so:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.className',  function(){
  alert('button clicked');
});
```

Comment: What about events that don't bubble?

Comment: the events are not being cloned.

Comment: @DouaBeri What I'm trying to say in my answer is you can't clone events but instead of having many events attached to many different elements, bind them to a parent like 'body' and listen for children like in the code example above.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Events that don't bubble aren't that often used, and even then the gain to have events bound on one element instead of a 100 is huge, not only for memory management...

Comment: Yes, delegation is good when possible and appropriate but we have no knowledge of which events the OP needs to handle. Moreover, handling of non-bubbling events is not at all uncommon. They include change, submit, focus, blur, load, unload.

Comment: Seems like submit works with the technique I suggested... http://jsfiddle.net/EWGUa/